# Pass variable in a session into another route [Python FLASK]

Tags: python, html, flask, session

## I'm developing a website using Flask to process a response call from API, show the Data, and then give the option to download the data in a .csv file for the user.

I have two API miner (miner_1 & miner_2) which would return data in a dictionary, consisting of multiple data types.
(string, data_frame, and  data frame which have been converted into HTML table format)

What I'm trying to do is :

1. Get 3 input from HTML form (params_a_input, params_b_input, and params_c_input)
2. Use those inputs for parameters in the API call to get the data
3. Display the data as text and HTML Table (so far I've succeeded to do these steps)
4. Add download to CSV button which would process the data frame into CSV and then download it to the user's computer.

Here is the Flask App Code :

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session, send_file, abort, make_response
from miner_1 import miner_1
from miner_2 import miner_2
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd
import io 
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "asdf" # <-- i read that we need secret_key to pass session data

main_title = "Website Name"

# @app.route >> to specify what is the URL path
@app.route("/")
def home():
  return render_template('index.html', main_title = main_title)

@app.route("/result", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
  params_a = request.form.get('params_a_input')
  params_b = request.form.get('params_b_input')
  params_c = int(request.form.get('params_c_input'))

  if params_b == 'option_1':
      data_result_1 = miner_1.getData(parameter_a=params_a, params_c=params_c)
      data_result_2 = ''
      df = data_result_1['data_frame'].to_json() # <- i changed the type to json in order to pass into the '/download' route.
      session['data'] = df
  
  elif params_b == 'option_2':
      data_result_1 = ''
      data_result_2 = miner_2.getData(parameter_a=parameter_a, parameter_c=params_c)
      df = data_result_2['data_frame'].to_json()
      session['data'] = df
  else:
      data_result = 'Need to select parameter_b'
  
  return render_template('index.html', main_title = main_title, data_result_1 = data_result_1, data_result_2 = data_result_2, df = df)

@app.route('/download')
def download():
  data = session['data']
  df = pd.read_json(data) 
  return send_file(
      io.BytesIO(df.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8').encode()),
      as_attachment=True,
      attachment_filename='df.csv',
      mimetype='text/csv')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host="127.0.0.1", debug=False) # For production never set debug=True
```

And Here are my index.html snippets :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>{{ main_title }}</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block navigation %}
<div class="container">
    <header class="d-flex justify-content-center py-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">Data Miner Tools</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  </div>
<div class="content">
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Data Miner</h1>
<p>With this tool, you can show the data and download it into csv</p>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form class="grid" action="/result" method="POST">
      <label for="params_a_input" class="form-label">Parameter A</label>
      <input type="text" name="params_a_input" class="form-control" id="params_a_input">
      <div class="form-text">Make sure your parameter spelling is right</div>
      <br>
      <label for="params_c_input" class="form-label">Parameter C</label>
      <input type="text" name="params_c_input" class="form-control" id="params_c_input">
      <div class="form-text">One Parameter C input approximately gets you 18 rows of data</div>
      <br>
      <label for="params_b_input" class="form-label">Parameter B</label>
      <select id="params_b_input" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="select one">
          <option selected value="option_1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="option_2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <br>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary file_submit" value="Get Data">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

{% if data_result_1 %}
<br>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <b>Data Result:</b> Analysing {{data_result_1['data_count']}} data
    </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              {{data_result_1['data_frame_html']|safe}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="{{url_for('download')}}" class="btn btn-outline-info">Download</a>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
{% endif %}
{% if data_result_2 %}
<br>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <b>Tiktok Result:</b> Analysing {{data_result_2['data_count']}} data
    </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              {{data_result_2['data_frame_html']|safe}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="{{url_for('download')}}" class="btn btn-outline-info">Download</a>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

and here are the sample result of miner_1/miner_2 :

{'data_count': 18,

'data_frame':

SOME DATA HERE

[18 rows x 25 columns],

'data_frame_html' : < HTML TABLE GENERATED FROM DATA FRAME >
}

---

Basically, what I'm trying to do is :

- Convert the data frame into JSON, then store it into session['data']
- Get the session['data'] in '/download' route, convert it back into data frame
- Send/download the data frame as a CSV file

When I run the program, I've successfully printed the data count and show the HTML table, but when I click the download button, it returns the error page with the error message like this :

> ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>

it seems like the problem is in this line :

> data = session['data']
> which returns None

Is there any solution to my problem here?

Sorry for the long question as this is my first question here,
I've tried to find the answer in a lot of StackOverflow pages for this problem and I haven't found the similar one yet.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the size of the data you put in the session object. Cookie-based sessions have a size limit. Try splitting that data into smaller chunks and see if that works.
Also consider change of syntax as per documentation:
[Docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#cookies)

`data = request.cookies.get('data')`